# How to remove the space below p elements in Outlook 2010?

Tags: css, html-email, outlook-2010

For some reason, there is about 20 pixels of unwanted space below my `p` element in `Outlook 2010`, although this particular element actually has no margin or padding applied to it.

How to remove this extra space?

Note: the text in the p element needs to be centered which is why I wrap it in p tags - I'm using Foundation For Emails which handles centering thus.

Comment: Can you maybe incluse some code?
I write Email code a lot and I almost never use the p tag. Maybe your p is inside a td and you could add a style tag to the td to fix your problem

Comment: A code sample would **really** help!

Answer (score 1):

Inline the `margin` and `padding` css for each `<p>` tag, like so:

```
 <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">paragraph 1</p>
 <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">paragraph 1</p>
 <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">paragraph 1</p>
```

Alternatively if it's an option, it's safer to stay away from `<p>` tags in email design because email clients render them so differently. May seem hacky, but using `<br>`s often gets the job done:

```
 paragraph 1 text.
 <br><br>
 paragraph 2 text.
 <br><br>
 paragraph 3 text with no <br>'s after it.
```

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome:

```
-webkit-margin-before: 0em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0em;
```